# How do I structure a firebase database for this case?

Tags: swift, firebase

Basically I would like to display every tobacco and all the available hookahs in a UITableView, based on if the tobacco segment or the hookah segment is pressed. First you should see the brand and after that the "products" (like all tobaccos or hookahs). 
So now, how exactly should the firebase database then look like? Because every product (hookah, tobacco) should have a "name", "brand", "rating" and "description".
The second question: How would I receive all these informations in my tableview by code? For now I am working with the following structure of sections for my tableview which is dependent on the var p if it is 0 or 1. Then it selects the section on index 0 or 1 (based on which segment is clicked).

```
var sections = [[Section(brand: "7 Days", products: ["Tabak1", "Tabak2", "Tabak3"], expanded: false),
                 Section(brand: "Zomo", products: ["Tabak1", "Tabak2", "Tabak3"], expanded: false)],
                [Section(brand: "Aeon", products: ["Shisha1", "Shisha2", "Shisha3"], expanded: false),
                 Section(brand: "Vendetta", products: ["Shisha1", "Shisha2", "Shisha3"], expanded: false)]]
```

[What the tableView looks like when its expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUlsv.png)

I would really appreciate any answer to any of the two problems.
Thank you!

Comment: This isn't a code writing service but we will be happy to help you with existing code you're having difficulty with. If you are asking how to [Read Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) from Firebase, it's pretty well covered in the documentation. To do your structure 'right' we would need more information. i.e. are you going to query your child nodes? If so, what for? How your data is structured is directly related to what you want to get out of it. Write some code and update your question when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply reading data and will never query for anything it's pretty straightforward

```
root
   all_data
      data_0 //created with .childByAutoId
         brand: "7 days"
         products:
            "Tabak1": true
            "Tabak2": true
       data_1
         brand: "Zomo"
         products:
            "Tabak1": true
            "Tabak2": true
       data_3
         brand: "Aeon"
         products:
            "Shisha1": true
            "Shisha2": true
```

however, this will lead to issues* if for example you want to query for all brands that have Tabak2 products. So here's an alternative that would enable you to easily determine the brand nodes that have Tabak2

```
root
   brands
      brand_0
         brand: "7 days"
      brand_1
         brand: "Zomo"
      brand_2
         brand: "Aeon"
   products_by_brand
      brand_0
         "Tabak1": true
         "Tabak2": true
      brand_1
         "Tabak1": true
         "Tabak2": true
      brand_2
         "Shisha1": true
         "Shisha2": true
```

And if you want to be super cool then here's a structure that cross references all products and brands which would allow for a variety of queries and allow you to link single products back to multiple brands and vice-versa

```
root
   brands
      brand_0 //created with .childByAutoId
         brand: "7 days"
         product_0: true //products should probably be in a child node
         product_1: true
      brand_1
         brand: "Zomo"
         product_0: true
         product_1: true
   all_products
      product_0
         name: "Tabak1"
         brand_0: true
         brand_1: true
      product_1
         name: "Tabak2"
         brand_0: true
         brand_1: true
```

*this can actually be accomplished via a deep path query

Answer (score -1):

brands -> products -> tobacco -> uniqueId -> name, rating and description

```
               -> hookah -> uniqueId -> name, rating and description
```

I'm not sure if you need to include the brand in the product details since that would be the main parent.
Hope this helps :)